# How to find consecutive elements in a collection in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

I am trying to find a way to find consecutive elements in a collection in Scala based on a desired element being in the first position.
I'd like to achieve this with functional programming, so I'm struggling on coming up with an approach.

Basically, I have a list `foo` which can contain either `A`, `B` or `C`. 'A' being the desired value, so it is necessary that 'A' is first, or else, the resulting `bar` should be empty.

From the **first** element, I need to extract the consecutive elements up until there is a change in the element value, then create a new list `bar` which contains the sequence of elements prior to the one that was different.

So for example, what I wanna do is

```
List('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B') => List('A', 'A')
```

At the same time, if the first element is **not** A, then the resulting List should be empty

```
List('B', 'A', 'A', 'C') => List()
```

I have tried to apply `foreach` on a List `foo` and check if the current element is the desired element to add it to a list, but due to Scala immutability (I know you can use mutable but I'd rather not) I don't know how to keep track of the previous elements and output the collection

Comment: Why is the second list empty? Shouldn't it contain one element - "b"?

Comment: No, it should only contain the sequence of desired elements

Comment: then your description is inaccurate - you said you want all the elements equal to the first one.

Comment: It says that if the first element is **not** A it should be empty. But I will add clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `takeWhile`:

```
list.headOption()
    .map(el => list.takeWhile(_ == el))
    .getOrElse(List())
```

If you want only `'A'`, then you can reduce the code to only the middle line, as in Brian's answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the first element always has to be `A`, then `takeWhile` does what you want.

```
scala> List('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B').takeWhile(_ == 'A')
val res3: List[Char] = List(A, A)
```